# How Jira plugin custom field value gets processed on the way to .vm templates

Tags: plugins, jira, velocity, atlassian-plugin-sdk

**Jira server 7.2.1. Custom field plugin.**

*The question follows this discussion*
[Can't understand, what does method getSingularObjectFromString do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17925377/cant-understand-what-does-method-getsingularobjectfromstring-do)
and some info from "Practical jira plugins"

I'm trying to implement a database custom field with basic value-displayValue logic. The field represents an external entity, so I'm storing ID as a value of the field, but displaying NAME. I have two .vm templates: edit and view. I'm trying to choose the right place to convert ID to NAME. I've overridden a method `getStringFromSingularObject(Object o)` to get the NAME from ID. It works absolutely fine in edit.vm. As a `$value` variable I get exactly the name, but in view.vm I still get an id as a `$value`. I've logged the method calls for the method for `AbstractSingleFieldType` and noticed that

1. when the page with my field gets rendered: Methods `getValueFromIssue, getDatabaseType, getObjectFromDbValue` are being called 4 times each (4 cycles in that order). So they are definitely not the place for a query.
2. when the field is rendered in the edit mode (so the edit.vm is processed) (i.e. create screen or edit screen, : the same methods are called 4 times and then `getStringFromSingularObject` and `getStringValueFromCustomFieldParams` are called and they return the name that I want.
3. when I simply refresh the view issue screen:  The method `getStringFromSingularObject` doesn't get called at all - **the source of my problem.**
4. currently in the view issue screen I see ID instead of the name, but when I click on the pencil (edit) I see the right value (the name). Moreover, in that case none of the methods are called. So I guess Jira processes both templates beforehand?

**edit.vm**

```
<div class="field-group">
    <label for="cFieldId">
        $customField.name $value
        #if($fieldLayoutItem.required)
            <span class="aui-icon icon-required">Required</span>
        #end
    </label>
    <select class="select cf-select" name="$customField.id" id="$customField.id">
        <option value="">None</option>
        #foreach ($id in $items.keySet())
            #if ($value && $value.equals($items.get($id)))
                <option value="$id" selected="selected">$items.get($id)</option>
            #else
                <option value="$id">$items.get($id)</option>
            #end
        #end
    </select>
</div>
```

**view.vm**

```
<div id="$customField.id-val" class="value type-select" data-fieldtype="select" data-fieldtypecompletekey="com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:select">
    $value
</div>
```

Once again, edit.vm works fine displaying name as a value and names as options. view.vm works wrong, displaying id.
So, the questions are:

1. why the method, that is kind of responsible for displaying a value doesn't get called on view?
2. where the `$value` is really getting set for the view.vm
3. what other options do I have for my purposes